# Remote Desktop inactive (black) when KODI is running

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, kodi, raspi-config

I have been using a pi 3B+ with Kodi, OS Buster, KODI 18.7 for a few years.
Per remote desktop I wrote scripts to control Kodi for example and tried these scripts while Kodi was running.

Now I've switched to pi 4B, not least because I don't like the micro SD cards and it's now possible to boot well and quickly from USB.

I have gone through the possible configurations in raspi-config, but I am not able to run kodi and the remote desktop at the same time. As soon as I exit kodi, the desktop is available, but not at the same time as I was used to with the pi 3B.

How can I read the settings from the 3B? In raspi-config I can't see what is currently set. Is there a file that can be read out with an editor?

Can you tell me what I have to set in raspi-config?

Many thanks in advance!

Greetings
M!ck

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

raspi-config is a bash script.

It has NO settings, it is just a front end to the many config files.

You can read the script to see what it does, although it is rather long and involved.

If you asked a more specific question about what settings you are interested in you may be able to get more details.

Comment: I only assume, that it has to do with the raps-config settings.

To be more specific:

I'm launching the raspberry desktop with VNC viewer. With Kodi I'm still on v18.7 as I was on RPi3B. On both RPi's I'm on Buster.
Now, on RPi4B the desktop is black as long as Kodi is active. If I quit Kodi, the desktop is available. With FileZilla I'm able to access Files, while Kodi is Active.
On RPi3B the desktop was available, whether Kodi was active or not.

What I want is, to have access to the remote desktop, whether Kodi is running or not.